# Jsoup - поиск по рандомной цифре в теге

Tags: jsoup, java, android

Ребят, не могу понять как в JSoup'е меняющиеся значения достать..
Имеется:

`<... class='s0'>`, `<... class='s1'>`, `<... class='s2'>`

Вытаскиваю так:

`String link7 = doc.select("[class=s0]").html();`

Но проблема в том, что он тогда вытаскивает значение только из "s0". Как сделать так, чтобы он ставил абсолютно любое число (хоть до 999999)? Пробовал и с `*` и с `(n)` и с `?` и с `#id`, но не выходит никак..

Answer (score 3):

В цикле формируешь строку и подставляешь.

```
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
String link = "#shedule-content tr:gt(0) " + "td:eq(" + k + ")";
time = doc.select(link);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать регулярные выражения. Например:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div[class~=s[0-9]*]");
```

Answer (score 0):

У класса `Element` есть методы [getElementsByAttributeValueStarting](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByAttributeStarting-java.lang.String-), [getElementsByAttributeValueContaining](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByAttributeValueContaining-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), [getElementsByAttributeValueMatching](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByAttributeValueMatching-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) c говорящими названиями. В вашем случае получить элементы и их текст с их помощью можно так:

```
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueStarting("class", "s");
//или
//Elements elements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("class", "s");
//или
//Elements elements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueMatching("class", "s[0-9]");

String innerText = elements.get(0).html;
```