# Jsoup, парсинг текста из ссылки с определенным атрибутом

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Предположим, что есть страница вот такого вида:

```
<tr>
    <td id="color" rowspan="5">Коэффициент </td> 
    <td id="color">8:30-10:00</td><td id="color" align="center">9,<br> доценты
    <a href="/whalemare">А.В. Пользователь</a> (ч.в.)&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="color" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Каким образом из нее можно вытащить слово "Коэффициент"? Была мысль сделать как
`td.attr("rowspan").text()`, т.е. якобы взять текст содержащийся в td с подобным атрибутом, но так делать нельзя :)

Видимо есть другой - правильный вариант. Подскажите, как взять текст содержащийся в определенном элементе в котором есть некоторый атрибут?

Потому что начинает казаться мне, что сделать это можно только лишь перебором

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [селекторы](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<table>"
                + "<tr>"
                + "    <td id=\"color\" rowspan=\"5\">Коэффициент </td>"
                + "    <td id=\"color\">8:30-10:00</td><td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">9,<br> доценты"
                + "    <a href=\"/whalemare\">А.В. Пользователь</a> (ч.в.)&nbsp;</td>"
                + "    <td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">&nbsp;</td>"
                + "</tr>"
                + "</table>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse( html );

        Elements elements = doc.select( "td[rowspan=5]" );

        System.out.println( "selector: " + elements.first().text() );
    }
}
```

Comment: В вашем примере не видно как выбрать элементы с определённым значение аттрибута. Это можно сделать так: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469503/17609

Comment: да можно и через селекторы

Comment: Спасибо за селекторы, мне кажется код покомпактнее получается, чем через функции

Answer (score 2):

Для поиска элементов, содержащих определённый атрибут с определённым значением есть метод [getElementsByAttributeValue("attributeName", "attributeValue")](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByAttributeValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) класса [Element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html). В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
String html = "<table>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "    <td id=\"color\" rowspan=\"5\">Коэффициент </td>"
            + "    <td id=\"color\">8:30-10:00</td><td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">9,<br> доценты"
            + "    <a href=\"/whalemare\">А.В. Пользователь</a> (ч.в.)&nbsp;</td>"
            + "    <td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">&nbsp;</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "</table>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse( html );

String searchedText = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("rowspan", "5").get(0).html();

System.out.println( "searchedText : " + searchedText  );
```

Comment: Вот тут ещё пара полезных методов для поиска элементов с заранее неизвестными значениями аттрибута: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469513/17609

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ и помощь в решении проблемы :)